# jQuery ajax - status OK, but response {"error":""}

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with a form that I use on a registration page. After filling all the fields and click the register button nothing happens, although the fields are correctly completed. The status code that I get after ajax is completed is OK, but in Response I get *{"error":""}*. I also added a *console.log(data)* in success function and I get *Object {error: ""}*, too. It worked great until now, I haven't done any change. Has anyone experienced same issues? Thank you in advance.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: userpro_ajax_url,
            data: form.serialize() + "&action=userpro_process_form&template="+form_data['template']+"&group="+form_data[ form_data['template'] + '_group' ]+"&shortcode="+encodeURIComponent(shortcode)+'&up_username='+up_username,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                userpro_end_load( form );
                alert("Error in jQuery.ajax while submitting a form:"+error);
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
```

`}



});`

Comment: And the code is ..?

Comment: And the backend code is?

Comment: userpro_ajax_url is actually the admin_ajax.php file

Comment: sorry @petter, I missed your question. the backend code for this case can be found here: https://github.com/bradryan13/userpro-custom/blob/master/functions/ajax.php, case: 'register' section.

Answer (score 0):

It is a jQuery question more then a Drupal question. The ajax success callback is triggered when the response come with status 200. It is not the matter of the response data. So it is possible to see `{error: ""}` in success callback. I would say that the API service is badly designed.